# Troquei o HD e não consigo re-abrir o projeto

Tags: visual-studio

Caros colegas.

Troquei o HD da máquina e re-instalei o VS 2017. Quando tento abrir um projeto já existente, o projeto está vazio e recebo a mensagem "o arquivo de projeto foi descarregado". Podem me ajudar por favor.

Obrigado.

Comment: Poderia colocar na pergunta um print do erro?

Comment: Tentou clicar com o botão direito no projeto vazio e escolhe a opção de "Recarregar" (Reload) ou "Adicionar projeto existente"? PS.: tentei adivinhar a tradução das opções em inglês.

Comment: Funcionou. Isto mesmo, cliquei como o botão direito no projeto e me deu as opções para resolver. Vocês são mesmo feras. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @GilbertoV.Gonçalves, que bom que funcionou! Poderia marcar minha resposta como a correta? Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clique com o botão direito no projeto vazio e escolha a opção de **Recarregar** ou **Adicionar projeto existente**. Uma destas opções será suficiente para resolver seu problema.

PS.: Tentei adivinhar a tradução das opções em inglês.